# Is it possible to know the selected option in Navigator.Share()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigator

In my web app using React, I am using `Navigator.share()` to share some links.

Is it possible to know, which medium user selected for the share?

Here is the code which I am using

```
if (navigator.share) {
    navigator.share({
        title: 'Web Fundamentals',
        text: 'Check out Web Fundamentals — it rocks!',
        url: 'https://developers.google.com/web',
    })
      .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
      .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
  } else {
    console.log('no share');
  }
```

}

Comment: Did you ever find this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not seem to be allowed. Per the W3C specifications:

> The user agent MUST NOT allow the website to learn which share targets are available, or the identity of the chosen target.

(from https://www.w3.org/TR/web-share/#share-method)

I have a feeling it is blocked for privacy reasons so that you don't know which apps a user has on their phone/device, and other things related to privacy.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the reformat of my answer. Makes it easier/quicker to read. I'm new to answering, and so didn't think to use the other field formatting options.